# Why does hostname -i show two values?

Tags: vmware-esxi, centos7, hostname

I've set up a new VM via VMWare and it runs CentOS7. Typically, when I run `hostname -i`, I get the IP address of the server I'm on. However, on this new VM, I get (these values are slightly altered):

```
hostname -i
fe09:204g:s3t0:s30f:O0ef%ens192 10.22.22.32
```

I recognize the 192... but why is this MAC address-like value showing up? I'm trying ssh to this new machine and in troubleshooting, I ran across this and wanted to understand before I proceed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That MAC address looking value is an IPV6 address.  If you have IPV6 enabled and routable on your ESXi host/guest, then the `-i` option will display all routable ip addresses.

If you use `--all-ip-addresses` or `-I`, this will omit loop-back and IPV6 link-local addresses.  It should just display any IPV4 addresses.

Answer (score 2):

You're seeing an IPv6 address there. The value after the `%` is the adapter that the IP address belongs to (in this case, `ens192`)

Although, one does wonder why your IPv6 address has non-hex characters in it. Does the output of `ip a` also show that IP address?